# Animate a <g> element in SVG with CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

In an SVG I have a `<g class="building">` that I'd like to move upwards on hover.

```
    <svg x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 595.3 841.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 595.3 841.9;" xml:space="preserve">
   <g class="building">
    <rect id="XMLID_1_" x="128.6" y="296.2"/>
 </g>
    </svg>
```

If the  was a `<div class="building">`, the CSS that I'd use would be:

```
.building {
position: relative;
top: -20px;
}
```

As `position` and `top` does not work in SVG, I'll obviously have to do this another way

How do I move up `<g class="building">` 20px?

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ynbyfLe/#&togetherjs=K32rqVxH1i)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8ynbyfLe/#&togetherjs=K32rqVxH1i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CSS transform to move it. Be careful as you've the same class defined for the g and the rect, you might want to reconsider that.

```css
 .building{fill:#72B62B;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .ground{fill:#030203;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
  
  .building:hover {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 595.3 841.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 595.3 841.9;" xml:space="preserve">
<g class="building">
<rect id="XMLID_2_" x="21.6" y="645" class="building" width="550" height="74.3"/>
</g>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
You dont need css to animate svg example heer:
<circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" />
<animate 
    xlink:href="#orange-circle"
    attributeName="cx"
    from="50"
    to="450" 
    dur="5s"
    begin="click"
    fill="freeze" 
    d="circ-anim" />
```